# Wordpress category php query running out of memory?

Tags: php, wordpress, memory, inline

I've got a wordpress page which has a map of a recent trip I did.

http://www.marksmayo.com/south-american-journey/

If I then write a basic php query function to list all posts in the category 'south america 2010', it works fine for 4-5 posts, but as I added posts to the category, it started running out of memory with this query (giving errors on the page), and now just doesn't load anything below the map.

The same code is on:

http://www.marksmayo.com/northern-europe-and-asia-mission/

and is currently working, but as I add more posts that'll presumably stop too.

The code is:

```
<?php

// The Query
query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'south america 2010', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<li><a href=';
        the_permalink();
        echo'>';
    the_title();

    echo '</a></li>';
endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();

?>
```

Comment: @John Green - PageSpike Or you can optimize the code so it works without greedily munching 600MBs of ram.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Two things:** use a simpler query and raise WP's memory allocation.

**Try this query**, which resets itself and can be used any number of times on a page (with php execution) or in a page template. Change the name of the category and showposts to a number, or -1 to show all.

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=mycategory&showposts=10'); ?>

<?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">

<?php the_title(); ?></a>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

**Raise WP's memory allocation** in wp-config.php with this near the top:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
```

and check the php.ini file in your account to see if php memory is set to a very low limit. You're on Bluehost, so if you don't have a php.ini file, you can add a single php.ini in php configuration in Cpanel and then edit it in your root account.

Bluehost will allow that much RAM for php, but be aware that Bluehost will throttle your account CPU sometimes; check Cpanel for your CPU usage and throttling amounts.

Comment: showposts is deprecated in version 2.1, you should use posts_per_page as @Mark Mayo uses in his own code.

Comment: some questions on that, new to Wordpress, how does one find this wp-config.php?  Will try checking the other settings in the meanwhile, thanks.

Comment: wp-config.php is the file in root where you entered all your database configuration to install Wordpress. If you used Bluehost's one click, it was generated automatically. But the file is still in root. Add that memory bump line right after the opening `<?php `

Comment: This really has nothing to do with the structure of the query(s) and everything to do with memory allocation and your Bluehost account. Check wp-config.php and see if there is a php.ini file in root.

Comment: I'm glad Community awarded you the bounty as it expired while I was travelling :(  I'd run into further memory issues as my feed stopped working - with a memory exhaustion in the feed, it needed sorting now! I'm up late at night in the arctic circle and just tried digging around in the config files, and indeed, there's no php.ini (created it, didn't seem to change much) - but after putting the entry in the wp-config.php, both the page I described above AND the feed are now working just fine.  Thank you so much for your detailed answer!

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the category ID rather than the category slug, so your query becomes:

```
query_posts( array ( 'cat' => 4, 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
```

(I'd assume a integer search would be faster, and less intensive.)
(obviously replace 4 with your category ID).

You could also remove the call for 'the_title()' and replace it with $post->post_title, as you have called the_post(), although to be honest I'm not 100% sure if this will have an impact.

Also if your on shared hosting you might consider a caching plugin. I'd recommend [W3 Total Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/), it will build flat files only running this query when the content actually updates.

Lastly, what preceeds your code snippet, you haven't already got this in a loop, so its looping through something else, AND running this every time, have you?

Comment: nothing preceeding it, I literally display the tripline map, and then run this code.  very little in the file at all.  Will try some of those tweaks now.

Comment: ok, If I restrict it to show 10 posts, that works, but if I use posts=-1 to show all in the cat, it blows out :(

Comment: and W3 Total Cache, after installing every page on my site was saying 'out of memory', 'exhausted' etc...trying to revert it now..

Comment: deactivating the plugin brought it back.  Not sure what settings would prevent that, the plugin itself looked really interesting, would love to play with it if it didn't bring down my site on activation :/

Comment: Hmm, anything odd going on in your functions.php file in your theme folder?

Comment: Might be time to speak to your host, and as Songdogtech said adding the memory setting to wp-config.php

Comment: Add the memory bump line to wp-config.php. Period.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you bump the memory limit in your `wp-config.php` file as suggested in a separate answer, you won't escape an out of memory problem down the road because of the massively wasteful manner that `$wpdb` manages memory. (It creates and stores two copies of each row it retrieves, in WP 3.0, and even that is a huge improvement as compared to what it did in earlier versions.)

I'd advise to limit the number of posts per page to something more reasonable, e.g. 50.

Comment: Sure, but if there are only 20 posts in a category and it's crashing now, setting it to 50 isn't going to help too much ;)  Thanks for the info though, did not know about that memory management 'feature' ;)

Comment: In this case you ought to report it as a bug in core.trac.wordpress.org... It's serious enough to mandate attention.

Answer (score 0):

Another minor addition that might help your query use less memory would be to add

no_found_rows=1

to it as it will help to reduce the query overhead.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query) class?
Maybe this would help:

```
// Query posts
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// Loop the result
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    // your impl
endwhile;

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: @Mark, I did look at your code, Wordpress Codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts says the difference between query_posts and WP_Query class, you are using query_posts in your code, that is intended only for the main loop.

Comment: sorry, that wasn't meant to sound that snarky ;)

Comment: I implemented your changes, and still get the same result.  If I use show_posts = 15 in the args, it displays, but 20 or more (or -1 for all) causes: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 76 bytes) in /home1/marksmay/public_html/wp-includes/load.php on line 569